# Enabling TLSv1.2 for Java Applets

Tags: java, swing, applet, tls1.2

Can anyone help me out in making Java Applets to use TLSv1.2 while making server side connections which runs strictly TLSv1.2

Below code seems not working, any help is appreciated

```
<APPLET archive="large_archive.jar"
                   code="MyApplet"
                   width="300" height="300">
         <PARAM NAME="java_arguments" VALUE="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2">
 </APPLET>
```

Comment: What java version ?

Comment: Client uses JDK7 and above versions in their machine

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Java Control Panel -> Java Tab -> click the View... button to see the installed JRE then you can enter in the Runtime Parameters your `-Dname=value`.

[image]